# Not picking up clients email address to send using MAIL function

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Max Design contact page</title>
<link href="mdstyle1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<?php

$required = array("firstName" => "First Name", 
              "surname" => "Surname",
              "email" => "Email Address",
              "telephone" => "Telephone");

foreach($required as $field => $label) {
if (!$_POST[$field]) {
$warnings[$field] = "*";
}
}


if ($_POST["firstName"] &&
 !ereg("[a-zA-Z]", $_POST["firstName"]))
 $warnings["firstName"] = "Please check First Name for errors";

if ($_POST["surname"] &&
!ereg("[a-zA-Z]", $_POST["surname"]))
$warnings["surname"] = "Please check Surname for errors";

if ($_POST["email"] &&
!ereg("^[^@]+@([a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$", $_POST["email"]))
$warnings["email"] = "Please check email for errors";

if ($_POST["telephone"] &&
!ereg("[0-9]", $_POST["telephone"]))
$warnings["telephone"] = "Please check Telephone for errors";


if (count($warnings) > 0) {

// sets the description of the sections of the form and must have an entry for each form         element
$description = array(); 
$description{"firstName"} = "First Name"; 
$description{"surname"} = "Surname"; 
$description{"telephone"} = "Telephone Number"; 
$description{"email"} = "Email Address"; 

?>


<div class="main-paragraph">

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<br />
<div class="warnings"> * Please fill in these boxes </div>
<br />
<br />

<TABLE BORDER=0>
<TR>
<TD><label>First Name</label>
 </TD><TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=30 NAME="firstName"
    VALUE="<?php echo $_POST["firstName"];?>"></TD>
 <TD><div class="warnings"><?php echo $warnings["firstName"];?></div></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD><label>Surname</label>
</TD><TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=30 NAME="surname"
    VALUE="<?php echo $_POST["surname"];?>"></TD>
 <TD><div class="warnings"><?php echo $warnings["surname"];?></div></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD><label>Email Address</label>
</TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=30 NAME="email"
         VALUE="<?php echo $_POST["email"];?>"></TD>
<TD><div class="warnings"><?php echo $warnings["email"];?></div></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD><label>Telephone</label>
 </TD>
 <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=15 NAME="telephone"
       VALUE="<?php echo $_POST["telephone"];?>"></TD>
 <TD><div class="warnings"><?php echo $warnings["telephone"];?></div></TD>
 </TR>

 </TABLE>
 <br />
 <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Send Enquiry">

 </FORM>
 </div> <!-- end of main paragraph -->


 <?php
 }
 else  { // start of send section

 //stuff that goes to the enquirer
 $clients_email = "From: sales@rmrc.co.uk";
 $headers2 = "From: simon@maxdesign.org.uk"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting MAX Design"; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you for contacting MAX Design. We will get back to you as soon as possible, 
           \n usualy within 48 hours. If you have any more questions, 
           \n please consult our website at www.maxdesign.org.uk/index";

 //prints out each field's title and contents in turn each on new line
 $body = "A quote request from the website:\n\n"; 
 foreach($_POST as $description => $value)  {   
   $body .= sprintf("%s = %s\n", $description, $value); 
   } 

 mail($email, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
 mail("sim.on@hotmail.co.uk", "MAX Design website enquiry", $body, $email); 
 header( "Location: http://www.maxdesign.org.uk/thank-you-for-quote-max-design.html" );

 } //end of send section

 ?>

</div><!--end of container/wrapper div -->
  </body>

  </html>
```

I am trying to send a fairly crudely formatted email (I am trying to get the email formatted a little bit using the $description variable but that isn't working either) from the clients website but the script won't send it to the clients email using the

```
$email
```

string so am having no luck. Have been at this for days now so any help really appreciated.

Simon

Comment: `ereg()` **Warning** This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. http://www.php.net/ereg

Comment: Plus, as Shankar mentioned below `$email` is not defined, or you would need to add `$email=$_POST['email];`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a variable called **`$email`** to your `mail()` which is not at all defined in the code. That is why your mail is not being sent. See below

```
mail($email, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
    //^^^^^ Undefined variable
```

**Solution** : Set the `$email` to some email.

Comment: @Shanker- Thanks for the heads up. I have now tried to define the variable and the form won't display at all. Will post amended code.